# Empty ssh invitation (no "user@host:~$") when run command after connect (sh script, sshpass)

Tags: bash, ssh, sshpass

Client OS: MacOS 12.1, Server OS: Linux Debian 9 (any server)

case 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p mypass ssh user@host.ru -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

works fine:
[image]

case 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p mypass ssh user@host.ru -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "cd /var/www ; git status ; /bin/bash"
```

[image]
Output of "git status" works fine, but
no "user@host:~$" message in output (input is active).

I tried:
/bin/bash
bash -l
(in server "echo $SHELL" shows /bin/bash)

How to fix it?

Comment: Please, never show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Moreover they affect accessibility negatively. Please copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.

Comment: Images shows RESULT, source for copy-paste available before images (sh script code). Posting unimportant text responses from the server in text will only confuse the reader. The subject matter is framed in text, debian's start text is not related to the subject matter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ssh -t` and **&&** inside commands list

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p mypass ssh -t user@host.ru -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "cd /var/www && git status && /bin/bash"
```